# Where is the constant for "HttpRequest.RequestType" and "WebRequest.Method" values in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to check the `RequestType` of an `HttpRequest` in ASP.NET (or `WebRequest.Method`). I know that I can just use the string values "`POST`" or "`GET`" for the request type, but I could have sworn there was a constant somewhere in some class in .NET that contained the values.

Out of curiosity I was wondering if anyone knew what class these string constants for `GET` and `POST` were in. I've tried searching online but I've had no luck, so I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http
    .Connect = "CONNECT"
    .Get = "GET"
    .Head = "HEAD"
    .MkCol = "MKCOL"
    .Post = "POST"
    .Put = "PUT"
```

Ultimately, though; since `const` expressions are burned into the caller, this is identical to using "GET" etc, just without the risk of a typo.

Comment: Interesting, why there is no DELETE method and "*"?

Comment: And it's missing OPTIONS and TRACE.

Comment: `PATCH` verb is also missing.

Answer (score 64):

Also exists [`System.Net.Http.HttpMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmethod) which can serve instead of enum. You can compare them `aMethod == HttpMethod.Get`, etc. To get string method name call e.g. `HttpMethod.Get.Method`.

Comment: This has the advantage to work in Asp.Net Core as well

Comment: I'm just wondering why they haven't declared those fields as constants instead of static readonly fields. The advantage of constants is that you can pass them as parameter defaults (i.e. `void Request(HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.Get)`).

Comment: @Shimmy The disadvantage of constants are that they're baked into the referencing assembly at compile-time via simple substitution. That means that if the assembly that defines the constants changes their values and is replaced, any referencing assemblies will retain the original, no wrong, constant values. How likely it is that HTTP methods will ever change, however, is another story...

Comment: `HttpMethod.Get.Method` is NOT a compile time constant :( where `System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http` are constants

Comment: The need for compile time constants is unavoidable regardless their advantages or disadvantages. For example, default parameters in a method signature. When I can not use System.Net.WebRequestMethods, I usually work around this by passing strings HttpMethod can use in its constructor. The trouble is, of course, their documentation doesn't explicitly say what happens when a bad string value is passed in so use this strategy at your own risk, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmethod.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 17):

In ASP.NET MVC they're in **System.Web.Mvc.HttpVerbs**.  But all methods that take one of these enum values also has a text override, as there is no complete set of HTTP verbs, only a set of currently defined values (see [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2518.txt) and [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) and [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)).

You can't create an enumeration that covers all verbs, as there is the possibility that verbs can be added, and [enumerations have versioning issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/01/05/50987.aspx) that make this impractical.

Answer (score 13):

In **ASP.NET Core** you will find a collection of http method strings in the [HttpMethods.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.4/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/HttpMethods.cs) class under the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace.

This class also offers boolean helpers such as `IsGet()` or `IsPost()` for better semantics.

Please note that these strings are exposed as `public static readonly string` and not as `constants`.

**UPDATE 2020-05-17:** `GetCanonicalizedValue(string method)` was added to the `HttpMethods.cs` class in ASP.NET Core v5, which returns the static instance equivalent to the provided string method name.

Comment: Great. Was able to validate with `handlerMethod.HttpMethod != HttpMethods.Post`